# What is user/external_edge

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

What is user/external_edge?
In my facebook app center.On Apps->My Ninja->Insights->Activity & Errors,I see my app request this much offen.and it is one hundred percent failure because permission.What permission should I set for my app?
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/open-graph-permissions/

I can't find any permission for that by the two url giving before.

Comment: It refers to any Open Graph action, of the form `/me/<namespace>:<action>`

Comment: thank you.I add the user_actions:<namespace> permission for my app.I will check if my problem will been solved.

Comment: Sorry.It seems be users's activity.I already add the publish_actions permission for my app.why permission problem here?

Comment: I find the problem.When one user login my app,I use getLoginUrl in php sdk , append the req_perms param in the url,but facebook do not recognize it.I have no idea.

Comment: req_perms was deprecated months ago - you should re-read the current login documentation - `scope` is the current parameter for the permissions selection